# Angular 5 IE browser application not showing Blank screen?

Tags: javascript, angular

I wanted to access the angular 5 application on IE 11 ,for that I have already updated the polyfiles files and all dependencies have been downloaded , but I am getting the error that **multiple definitions of a  property not allowed in strict mode** , the problem is I am not able to understand exactly where it is breaking I got line number but its too complex to read , I am getting this error in man.bundle.js file compiled through angular cli.

Comment: Are you by any chance compiling it with the `--prod` flag? Or `enableProdMode()` ?

Comment: no only ng serve cmmand I m using

Comment: only IE browser throwing me this error , it is working fine in all the browsers.

Comment: Hmmm weird then, `main.bundle.js` should not be minified, but it sounds like it is. When you say that the code `is too complex to read`, do you mean it's minified, or just that it's readable but you don't understand what it does?

Comment: exactly jeremy ,it is readable but i dont understand what it does ,but i wanted to tell you this is breaking in eval() call where it is exporting and importing the webpack module

Comment: Ah, I get it. In that case, go up in the error stack. There is an error stack in Chrome's console (which function that called which function that called the erroring function), try to find yours in there.